# Mongodb aggregate use match with lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have this code here:

```
Achievement.aggregate([
    {"$match": {}}, 
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "achievementcompleteds", // collection name in db
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "achievement_id",
            as: "completed"
        }
    }]).then((results) => {
```

So what it does it shows the ahcievements to user and also shows if its completed next to the achievement. But the problem is that if one user completes achievement then for every user it is shown that it is completed. So I need to get `achievementcompleteds` by `user_id` somehow.

`achievemets`: `_id` `title` etc

`achievementcompleteds:` `_id` `achievement_id` `user_id`

**EDIT**

Okay so this code:

```
 Achievement.aggregate([
       {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "achievementcompleteds", // collection name in db
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "achievement_id",
            "as": "completeds"
        }},
        { "$match": {"completeds.user_id": user._id}}
    ]).then((results) => {
```

returns me only achievements for user that are completed. So the problem is that it doest me return all achievements list right now.

Comment: What version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet `"mongodb": "^3.1.6"`, `"mongoose": "^5.3.0"`,

Comment: `"mongodb": "^3.1.6"` I think this is mongodb native driver version. Check the version with mongo shell or robomongo or compass